# Using a batch file, how do I delete files that have a certain string of characters inside?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a .bat files that can allow me to delete the file if a certain string of characters appears inside. For example, if I want to delete files that have the string harp inside of it and the files in the folder are:

```
harp1.txt
mellowharp.txt
highharplow.txt
```

I want to be able to delete all of these files. I figured out how to do it if it starts or ends with the string, by merely writing

```
del harp*.*
del *harp.*
```

But I can't figure out how to do it if harp is found in the middle of the string.

I've tried things like putting an asterisk on each side of harp for a catch all case, but obviously that doesn't work.

This is literally my first day and experience with .bat files, and I would really appreciate any help I get on this, but please by gentle and explain EVERYTHING because I'm coming into this with no knowledge whatsoever.

Comment: If harp is contained in the file name, or the text in the file?

Comment: In the file name, sorry I just realized I could have been clearer

Comment: Are the files in a certain directory, or scattered throughout the hard drive?

Comment: They are all in the same directory. It's honestly quite a simple problem.

I figured if I wrote something like 

del *harp*.* 

it would check if the file name had harp inside of it at all, but it doesn't delete it as I want.

Comment: And your absolutely sure `del *harp*.*` didn't work? Works fine on my end

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. I've made multiple files to test, and as long as harp is nested between other characters that doesn't work. I can't imagine why it doesn't work, but I can only report what I see :/

Comment: If you are using batch on Windows, then `del *harp*` should work. If it is not, then there is something important you are not telling us, or else something very unusual.

Comment: It is somewhat bizarre that double wild doesn't work, can you enter this `DIR *harp*` and see all the files that should fit the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since using `del *harp*.*` didn't work for you, you could iterate through all the files in the specified directory then delete when the substring "harp" is found in the file name.

This should do it:

```
@echo off

for /f %%F in ('dir /b * ^| find /i "harp"') do del %%F

echo Files Successfully Deleted...
pause>nul
exit
```

Make sure this `.bat` file is in the same directory as your other files.

Explanation:

> The `for` command loops through the files in the directory and assigns them to the variable `%%F` and searches for the substring "harp" in the file name. Then, when found, the `do del %%F` tells the program to delete the file (`%%F`). Read more about `for` statements [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).
>
> The `echo` command simply prints a line of text to the console window. To read more about `echo` [click here](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html).
>
> The `pause>nul` pauses the program and waits for the user to press a key, but without any text being displayed on screen. (The normal text that would appear would be ***press any key to continue...***). More about `pause` [here](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html).
>
> The exit command stops the program. More on `exit` [here](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html).

Answer (score 0):

@UnknownOctopus solution is almost perfect but would fail with file names containing spaces. So for example a file called 'my harp file.mp3' would be passed to dell as 'my'.
to improve it use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b *harp*') do del "%%F"
```